# Parse website content after log in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have been looking at the solutions posted on stack-overflow about parsing web content after log in with jsoup, however there wasn't any solution for my problem, or i was not able to implement it. Can anyone please give me clear understandings on how to:

1. Login to one page with user details, where the submit button doesnt have a name, it only has ID
2. Parse the data of the second page which requires login access.

Comment: It is hard to help you without actually seeing HTML code you want to parse.

Comment: try the example from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183108/unable-to-parse-website-after-successful-log-in-jsoup)