# Unable to parse website after successful log in JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I successfully log into website using JSoup library, store the cookies so that i can use them for the second document where access is required. However the second document parses the data as if i am not logged in.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> loginCookies = null;


     Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("login page")
             .method(Connection.Method.GET)
             .execute();

     loginCookies = loginForm.cookies();

     Document document = Jsoup.connect("login page")
             .data("cookieexists", "false")
             .data("username", "user")
             .data("password", "pass")
             .data("loginbtn", "Log in")
             .cookies(loginCookies)
             .post();


    Document document2 = Jsoup.connect("Page with access required")
        .cookies(loginCookies)
        .get();

    System.out.println(document2);
}
```

}

What can be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store and reuse cookies which contain information about your session, which means you need to store them from server response which you get after passing your credentials, not just from empty form.

So try with

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("login page")
        .data("cookieexists", "false")
        .data("username", "user")
        .data("password", "pass")
        .data("loginbtn", "Log in")
        //.cookies(loginCookies)
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();

//here `loginForm` connected to server with your credentials
//and server returned response with cookies containing informations
//required to continue session so you should store them
//and reuse to access farther pages
Map<String, String> loginCookies  = loginForm.cookies();

Document document2 = Jsoup.connect("Page with access required")
        .cookies(loginCookies)
        .get();

System.out.println(document2);
```

Comment: What if the site requires csrf token check? You need to go to the login page first, in order the website to put cookie with csrf token, and then to set the same token in the data that you are sending to the website when you login. How the website will compare the cookie from the form if I don't send cookies as well?

Comment: @niki4ko You may want to create separate question for that problem. To be honest I am not really sure what problem you see and trying to solve.